# How to compare the last digits of consecutive integers in a list

Tags: python, digit

In a program that I'm making I need to evaluate the last digit of each integer in a list and compare it to the last digits of the next two integers. The code I'm using works for 2 integers, but when I tried to add another integer it didn't work. The code for two integers is

```
from collections import Counter
ctr = Counter((n0%10,n1%10) for n0,n1 in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]))
```

The code I tried for three integers is

```
from collections import Counter
ctr2 = Counter((n0%10,n1%10,n2%10) for n0,n1,n2 in zip(my_list,my_list,my_list[1:]))
```

`ctr2` always outputs 0 though. I'm sure it's a simple fix I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post `my_list` and your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **slice each list one element further**, like:

```
Counter((n0%10,n1%10,n2%10) for n0,n1,n2 in zip(my_list,my_list[1:],my_list[2:]))
```

So the first list in the `zip(..)` is not sliced at all (starts at index 0), the second at index 1 (`[1:]`), the third at index 2 (`[2:]`) and if you want more lists, each list should start at the next index.

You can make it more elegantly, by using a function where you compare an *arbitrary* amount of numbers. Like:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import Counter

def count_last_digits(data,n=2):
    slices = [islice(data,i,None) for i in range(n)]
    return Counter(tuple(x%10 for x in t) for t in zip(*slices))
```

For `n=2` this will take every two consecutive numbers into account. For `n=3` this will take every three consecutive numbers into account, and so on.

For instance:

```
>>> count_last_digits([14,25,13,2])
Counter({(4, 5): 1, (3, 2): 1, (5, 3): 1})
>>> count_last_digits([14,25,13,2],3)
Counter({(5, 3, 2): 1, (4, 5, 3): 1})
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank You

Comment: When I use the count_last_digits function you posted with a list as data and then print count_last_digits(my_list) it prints Counter() is there something else I need to do?

Comment: What is `my_list`? If the list is empty or has only one element, than it cannot count any values. Since you can not compare the digits of two numbers if only one is given.

Comment: @Sekou: I found out I made a typo (forgot a `None`). Now it should work. My apologies.